# How to load local browser video name in canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I need some help with a **video player** in unity. how to show selected video the file name in **canvas** at runtime

Comment: What is your method of getting the video are you using any frameworks where is it loading from(file storage,url?)

Comment: Please post more information so we can better answer your question